# Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ is $p$-subgroup of $G$. Show that

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ is $p$-subgroup of $G$. Show that, if $f$ is a automorphism of $G$, there exist a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$ such that $P$ contains $f(H)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$, then so is $f(H)$.

Comment: If $f(H)$ is also a $p$-subgroup of $G$, evidently $P$ contains $f(H)$. Can you give me more details?

Comment: @chuyenvien94 One of the Sylow theorems is that every $p$-subgroup lies in a $p$-Sylow subgroup, and $f(H)$ is a $p$-subgroup, so....

Comment: Why $f(H)$ is $p$-subgroup of $G$? Can you explain more precisely to me?

Comment: $\left|f\left(H\right)\right|=\left|H\right|=p^{n}$ so $f(H)$ is also a $p$-subgroup of $G$

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Yes, you've got it.